# Python import pyd module fails in Jupyter, works in IDLE

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

My company provided a .pyd file to work with a new API of our internal software. I followed their instructions using Python's IDLE (and python in command prompt) and it worked without any issues. When I tried the same steps using a Jupyter Notebook, I get an error

```
# modname.cp38-win_amd64.pyd located in installation folder of foobar
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(r"C:\Program Files (x86)\foo\bar\bin64")
import modname
```

This is the point when IDLE continues and Jupyter Notebook says

```
----> 1 import modname
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing modname: The specified module could not be found.
```

I installed Jupyter notebook by using "pip install jupyterlab" and run it from a command prompt in Windows. I checked using print(sys.executable) and both IDLE and Jupyter are using the same Python installation, and I also tried running python directly in the command prompt in case python.exe (Jupyter and CMD's) and pythonw.exe (IDLE's version) differed, but it worked under command prompt.

I used print(sys.path) to check for path differences but everything in IDLE's path is also in Jupyter's. All of the previous answers point to things I have tried or assume the user is using Anaconda. I can continue without using a Jupyter Notebook but had hoped to try a new workflow.

UPDATE: More Information
I loaded the pyd in [Dependencies](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies) (updated open source Dependent Walker), and all of the dlls were either in the current PATH folders or C:\Windows\System32. I added the System32 folder to the path using sys.path.append with the same result.

I also used print(os.environ) in both IDLE and Jupyter to look for any differences. IDLE had a 'Home' key (C:\Users\MyUserName) that Juptyer didn't have so I added it with the same result. Jupyter had a few others but they didn't seem relevant (terminal color, lang, etc.)

Comment: Try using sys.path.append(r"localhost\C:\Program Files (x86)\foo\bar\bin64"). Maybe, the error is because Jypyter is web based

Comment: No such luck. I tried it with the same result. I also tried "os.startfile(another.exe)" that is also located in the same path (...\foo\bar\bin64) and the program launched, so it is definitely pointing to the correct directory and adding it to the path successfully.